# Merging two sorted lists by using linked lists

Tags: c

I am merging two sorted lists which are sorted in ascending order. I am using two functions to achieve this task:

1. The first one is Node *MergedSort(Node *a, Node *b), which takes head node of both the sorted lists and merges them together.
2. And one more utility function void MoveNode(Node **dest, Node **source) which takes the head node of source linked list and puts it on top of the destination list. And makes the head of source linked list point to its next element.

Here is my code for doing this task:

```
typedef struct container{
       int data;
       struct container *next;
 } Node;

void MoveNode(Node **dest, Node **source){
    Node *newNode = *source;
    //Now source points to its second node;
    *source = newNode->next;
    //Connecting newNode to dest.
    newNode->next = *dest;
    //Now destination head points  to newNode
    *dest = newNode;
    return;
}

Node *MergedSort(Node *a, Node *b){
    Node dummy;
    Node *tail = &dummy;
    dummy.next = NULL;

    while(1){
            if (a == NULL){
                    tail->next = b;
                    break;
            }
            else if (b == NULL){
                    tail->next = a;
                    break;
            }
            else if (a->data < b->data){
                    MoveNode(&(tail->next), &a);
            }
            else{
                    MoveNode(&(tail->next), &b);
            }
            tail = tail->next;
    }
    return (dummy.next);
}
```

Now the problem is this,if I do a small change in this code, i.e. define dummy to be pointer to Node, it gives me segmentation fault. This is the faulty code, with just one slight change, the declaration of dummy is now Node *dummy:

```
void MoveNode(Node **dest, Node **source){
    Node *newNode = *source;
    //Now source points to its second node;
    *source = newNode->next;
    //Connecting newNode to dest.
    newNode->next = *dest;
    //Now destination head points  to newNode
    *dest = newNode;
    return;
}

Node *MergedSort(Node *a, Node *b){
    Node *dummy;  // This slight change gave me segmentation fault.
    Node *tail = dummy;
    dummy->next = NULL;

    while(1){
            if (a == NULL){
                    tail->next = b;
                    break;
            }
            else if (b == NULL){
                    tail->next = a;
                    break;
            }
            else if (a->data < b->data){
                    MoveNode(&(tail->next), &a);
            }
            else{
                    MoveNode(&(tail->next), &b);
            }
            tail = tail->next;
    }
    return (dummy->next);
}
```

I am not able to figure out, why the program crashes when I do this though the earlier implementation and latter implementation, logically look same to me.

Comment: How does `Node` look like ?

Comment: `dummy->next = NULL;`. That is invalid since `dummy` is not intialised. Very likely will cause a seg fault on that line.

Comment: I added the definition of Node to the code. Please have a look.

Comment: But the same un initialization is in the former implementation the only difference being dummy is not pointer to node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dummy` is a **structure**. `tail` points to the address of that structure. The structure's variable `next` point to NULL. So far all good.

```
Node dummy;
Node *tail = &dummy;
dummy.next = NULL;
```

`dummy` is a **pointer to a structure**. `tail` points to the address of that structure - OK. The (dereferenced[1] - NOT OK) structure's variable `next` is illegally accessed because `dummy` has not been initialized yet.

```
Node *dummy;  // This slight change gave me segmentation fault.
Node *tail = dummy;
dummy->next = NULL;
```

---

[1] `dummy->next` is equivalent to `(*dummy).next`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you do this

```
dummy->next = NULL;
```

`dummy` has not been initialized yet. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.

You don't need `dummy` at all - simply assign `NULL` to `tail`, rename it to `head`, and pass `&head` to `MoveNode`. Return `head` to complete the fix:

```
Node *MergedSort(Node *a, Node *b) {
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node **tail = &head;
    while(1) {
        if (a == NULL){
            *tail = b;
            break;
        } else if (b == NULL){
            *tail = a;
            break;
        } else if (a->data < b->data){
            MoveNode(tail, &a);
        } else{
            MoveNode(tail, &b);
        }
        tail = &((*tail)->next);
    }
    return head;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/subIiX)

Comment: I did that because I am always adding elements to the tail of the list, if I don't use dummy I will loose access to the head of the list, because tail is always pointing to the tail of the list.

Comment: @AnkitMishra You can keep a pointer to `head` separately. See the edit and the demo for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got this problem and your implementation of it, solves the problem completely.

Comment: @AnkitMishra You are welcome! If the problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that the problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.